# How many different strings of length 12 containing exactly five a's can be chosen over the following alphabets?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

(a) 
The alphabet {a, b}

(b) 
The alphabet {a, b, c}

For a: 
I got $\binom{12}{5}$

For b: $2^7 \cdot \binom{12}{5}$

Normally, I would never waste the users time by asking a "yes" "no" question. But since, for some reason, authors these days have decided that including answers to exercises at the end of their books is a horrible idea, I have to go ahead and waste everyone's time if I want to learn a simple method. So, can someone please tell me if my answers are right?

Thanks, and sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Yes they are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers to both questions are correct.

Answer (score 2):

For question (a), $5$ out of the $12$ places in the string should contain an $a$. We can choose these places in $\binom{12}{5}$ ways. Then the remaining $7$ places should each contain a $b$. But since we already chose the places for the $a$'s, the end result is $\binom{12}{5}$.

For (b), use the same reasoning to choose the places for the $a$'s. Then, the remaining $7$ places should each be either $b$ or $c$. So we have to choose $7$ times from the set $\{b,c\}$ with repetition, which can be done in $2^7$ ways, hence the result is $\binom{12}{5}\cdot 2^7$.